# Evaluation and assignment in if statement

Tags: php

I'm wondering, will this work with any major PHP versions?

```
if ($foo != $bar && '' != $str = some_function($some_variable))
    echo $str;
```

The `some_function($some_variable)` returns a string, which is assigned to the `$str` variable and then checked if is an empty string. The `$str` variable is used later of course.

Will be the output of the `some_function` assigned to the `$str` variable in every major PHP version (>5)? I couldn't find any information on this. Thanks.

I'm currently running 5.4 and it's working.

**Edit:** To avoid further confusion, the `$foo != $bar` precedes the other expression because the `$str` variable is only used inside the if statement. Sorry, I forgot to clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not see why this would not work in any PHP version (> 5).
Tested here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a295189c50c191bbd0241d4e8ea4e3081cdb40ae

Worked with all the versions from 4.4.9 and up.

**Note:** Because you are using the && operator, the code after the && will not be run if $foo != $bar already returns false, since the second expression cannot change the outcome of the && operator, therefore it will simply ignore it.

If the assignment is intented to always take place, then change the order of the expressions.

```
if ('' != $str = some_function($some_variable) && $foo != $bar)
    echo $str;
```

Comment: For your example take for foo and bar 2 and it will NOT work!

Comment: The question did not specify whether this was intented or not, however it is good to note that the assignment will not take place in the case that foo does not equal bar, will edit my answer.

Comment: Yes it does: *The $str variable is used later of course.* <- It has to be initialized ! (BTW: You also didn't say that this doesn't check if it is a string)

Comment: @Rizier123 I'm at a loss to se how this doesn't work. In the sandbox I tried various combos and they all worked. Please specify clearly how it doesn't work. The if statement initialises $str.

Comment: What I still don't understand is that in this expression `'' != $str = some_function($some_variable)` why is the `$str = some_function($some_variable)` evaluated first and not the `'' != $str` as I would expect?

Comment: The statement should use !== or === though as '' == false == null.

Comment: @dewd ThiJs Riebzebeek changed the code and initialized the variable before the if statement

Comment: @ErnestMarcinko (FYI: From the manual `Note:
Although = has a lower precedence than most other operators, PHP will still allow expressions similar to the following: if (!$a = foo()), in which case the return value of foo() is put into $a.` It allows it, but it doesn't means it's perfectly correct! That's why i said that in my answer)

Answer (score 4):

Yes it does work, but to get it working like you want you have to put brackets around the assignment, because the comparison has a higher precedence then the assignment! ([operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php))

Also if `$foo != $bar` is false the `$str` would never been initialize so also change the order, so that it get's assigned ever time.

So use this:

```
if ('' !== ($str = some_function($some_variable)) && $foo != $bar)
     //^^^ ^ See here                   And here^
     //| '!==' to also check the type
```

Comment: Do we want `!==` for these string comparisons just in case of type juggling?

Comment: @sjagr updated it! (But OP doesn't say if `$bar` and `$foo` are also strings so i didn't updated it there)

Comment: The interesting this is, that the brackets does not change the outcome. It works correctly. The only possible explanation is that it evaluates the function first, compares the values, then assigns?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make it clear and not confusing by using brackets and curly braces. Example:

```
if (($foo != $bar) && '' != ($str = some_function($some_variable)) ) {
       echo $str;
}
```